# Наложить прозрачное изображение на видео FFMPEG

Tags: изображения, видео, ffmpeg

Имеем видео 1.mp4 и картинку gr.png
Надо наложить картинку с прозрачностью 50% поверх видео и растянуть ее по размерам видео.
Нагуглил такое:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i gr.png -filter_complex "[1:v]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.5*alpha(X,Y)'[zork]; [0:v][zork]overlay" -vcodec libx264 out.mp4 -y
```

Проблема в том, что не знаю как растянуть\сжать картинку под размер видео.
Знающие люди, помогите пожалуйста.